# Xamarin Essentials WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync method doesn't return any result

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-signin, xamarin.essentials, webauthenticator

I have added a WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync method in my xamarin forms app with start up Url as "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
and call back url as "myapp://"

I have also tried with call back url as "com.googleusercontent.apps.{clientId}:/oauth2redirect"
I am doing this to add google login in my xamarin forms app.
On this browser with available google accounts are been showing up and after successful completion of email authentication it returns to app but result is not returned from WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync method.
On second time invocation of this method returns the first invocation result as cancelled by user and the browser opens again for second time email authentication.

But it works in ios.

I have added 3 classes

```
public class Auth0Client
{
    private readonly OidcClient oidcClient;

    public Auth0Client(Auth0ClientOptions options)
    {
        var discovery = new DiscoveryPolicy
        {
            ValidateEndpoints = false,
            Authority = "https://accounts.google.com"
        };
        oidcClient = new OidcClient(new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = $"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            ClientId = options.ClientId,
            Scope = options.Scope,
            RedirectUri = options.RedirectUri,
            Browser = options.Browser,
            ProviderInformation = options.ProviderInformation,
            Policy = new Policy
            {
                Discovery = discovery,
                RequireAccessTokenHash = false
            },
        });
    }

    public IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.IBrowser Browser
    {
        get
        {
            return oidcClient.Options.Browser;
        }
        set
        {
            oidcClient.Options.Browser = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<LoginResult> LoginAsync()
    {
        return await oidcClient.LoginAsync();
    }
}
public class Auth0ClientOptions
{
    public Auth0ClientOptions()
    {
        
    }

    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public IBrowser Browser { get; set; }
    public ProviderInformation ProviderInformation { get; set; }
}

public class WebBrowserAuthenticator : IBrowser
{
    public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            WebAuthenticatorResult result =  await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                new Uri(options.StartUrl),new Uri(options.EndUrl));

            var url = new RequestUrl(options.EndUrl)
                .Create(new Parameters(result.Properties));

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                Response = url,
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel,
                ErrorDescription = "Login canceled by the user."
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In view model we are creating authoclient

```
private async void NavigateToGoogleLogin(object obj)
    {
        string clientId = null;
        string redirectUri = null;

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                clientId = AppConstants.GoogleiOSClientId;
                redirectUri = AppConstants.GoogleiOSRedirectUrl;
                break;

            case Device.Android:
                clientId = AppConstants.GoogleAndroidClientId;
                redirectUri = AppConstants.GoogleAndroidRedirectUrl;
                break;
        }
        var auth0client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions()
        {
            Domain = "accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            ClientId = clientId,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = AppConstants.GoogleScope,
            Browser = new WebBrowserAuthenticator(),
            ProviderInformation = new ProviderInformation
            {
                IssuerName = "accounts.google.com",
                AuthorizeEndpoint = AppConstants.GoogleAuthorizeUrl,
                TokenEndpoint = AppConstants.GoogleAccessTokenUrl,
                UserInfoEndpoint = AppConstants.GoogleUserInfoUrl,

                KeySet = new JsonWebKeySet(),
            },
        });

        var loginResult = await auth0client.LoginAsync();
    }
```

We are using below constants in authoclient object creation

```
internal static string GoogleScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

internal static string GoogleAuthorizeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";

internal static string GoogleAccessTokenUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";

internal static string GoogleUserInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";
```

Xamarin forms version:5.0.0.2012
Xamarin essentials: 1.7.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you [use the Intent Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android#:~:text=Android%20requires%20an%20Intent%20Filter%20setup%20to%20handle%20your%20callback%20URI.%20This%20is%20easily%20accomplished%20by%20subclassing%20the%20WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity%20class%3A) setting for your callback URI in Android?

Comment: yes I have used like below.

[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
   Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },DataScheme = "com.googleusercontent.apps.{androidClient id}",
    DataHost= "/oauth2redirect")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }

Comment: I have added  this in andorid manifest

<intent>
<action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService"/>
</intent> @DongzhiWang-MSFT

Comment: You can try to change `DataScheme = "com.googleusercontent.apps.{androidClient id}", DataHost="/oauth2redirect"` to `DataScheme="myapp"`, make a breakpoint in the code to track and check whether the callback is normal run. Can you provide some code where you use WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync?

Comment: We have tried with "myapp" in datascheme too. But no progress. Am following this maui blog
https://auth0.com/blog/add-authentication-to-dotnet-maui-apps-with-auth0/

Instead of maui web authenticator we are using xamarin essentials web authenticator. @DongzhiWang-MSFT

Comment: I have also added the code in the question section @DongzhiWang-MSFT

Comment: You said: "returns the first invocation result as canceled by user". However, by looking at your code, I found that this is the error description in your `catch` which indicates that there is an error in your `try` statement. You can try to run the code without a `try...catch` block and add a breakpoint in the code to see the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250219/discussion-between-sushmitha-rao-b-and-dongzhi-wang-msft).

Comment: okay, I posted a message in chat.

Comment: Experiencing same issue here . Did you ever figure thie out ?

Comment: @JamesWilkinson

Please try by adding 

protected async override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
base.OnNewIntent(intent);
 }
in mainactivity


[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "your value" },
    DataPath = "Your value", DataPathPrefix = "your value")]